# Dialogflow CX - How to reference webhook tag in flexible webhook request payload?

Tags: webhooks, dialogflow-cx

I started using a [flexible webhook](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/webhook#flexible) in Dialogflow CX to manage some smaller backend tasks. Given the simplicity of my backend tasks, I prefer the flexible webhook which is less overhead especially when responding to the request.

Now I have two similar, but not exactly identical scenarios on different dialogflow pages in which I'd like to re-use the same Dialogflow webhook definition. For this purpose, I assigned a tag to the webhook at each page that allows the backend service to differentiate between scenarios.

For my flexible webhook, I need to specify the payload of the webhook request in the webhook definition. While I noticed that the webhook tag is part of the standard webhook request, I wonder how I could reference the webhook tag in my custom payload. Unfortunately, the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/parameter) does not clearly tell how the correct reference looks like.

This is how my flexible webhook payload looks like currently:

```
{
  "my_param_1": "$session.params.param_1,
  "my_param_2": "$session.params.param_2",
  ...
  "webhook_tag": "?"
}
```

I already tried:
`"$webhook.params.tag"` , `"$session.fulfillmentInfo.tag"` and "`"$fulfillmentInfo.tag"`. All of them resulted in the webhook not being called with following error:

```
    ...
    "FunctionExecution": {
            "Webhook": {
              "Status": {
                "ErrorCode": "INTERNAL"
              }
          }
       },
     ...
       "webhookStatuses": [
    {
      "code": 13
    }
  ]
```

I noticed in the standard webhook request I can find the tag like follows:

```
{
  ...
  "fulfillmentInfo": {
      "tag": "my_tag"
  }
  ...
}
```

So I expect I can also reference the tag in the flexible webhook request.

Comment: Workaround for now: In the fulfillments, I use a custom preset parameter that I initialize to my desired value. I do collect this parameter value from the customer. In the flexible webhook request payload, I can then reference the parameter just like other session parameters using $session.params.my_param_name

Answer (score 1):

Code 13 only has happened to me in the past because of a spelling mismatch between a parameter name and the reference in the `$session.params.parameter_name`